# Handlebars dot notation path expressions returning blank values, but normal (non-path) expressions work

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using handlebars for templating, when I write {{user}}, I get the full user object showing all the key value pairs, but when I write {{user.name}} for example, it returns a blank value. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I've added a response. Please, always include code and more evidences when asking a question here in Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I also have had problems once while trying to access object properties with dot-notation in Handlebars. Although it is a possible option, I suggest that you handle the object data in the back-end and send the View Model (or DTO, depending on your application) with the final data to be displayed in front-end. It is a better practice in my opinion and would also eliminate the need of accessing object properties in your View.

If by some reason you wish to access only with dot-notation, please update your question including your application's front and back-end code, so that we can study your problem.

Comment: I ended up up reverting to an older version of Handlebars and it worked fine for some reason. This is a repo I haven't touched in a year and it was using Handlebars 4.1.2, I updated it to 4.7.6 and it broke, reverting back to the old version fixed the issue which is good enough for me right now :P just trying to get the code to a working state.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve the problema, Zain. Thanks for sharing your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I never ended in such issue but usually I encountered some issues where the expected object was empty instead of having data. What you can do is debug yourself your data by printing all properties with something like that (depending on thedata you expect):

If you expect an arry do that :

```
{{#each myArray}}
    Index: {{@index}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

If you expect an object you can print all properties with this :

```
{{#each myObject}}
    Key: {{@key}} Value = {{this}}
{{/each}}
```